# Delete keys with missing values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My dataframe is

```
ID   Alphabet   Number1    Number2
1       A         NaN         9
1       A          3          5
1       A          1          4
1       A          2          4
2       B          7          3
2       B          2          8 
2       B          4          1
2       B          8          5
3       C          2          2
3       C          1          9
4       D          2          3
4       D          6          2
4       D          8         NaN
```

I got unique Alphabets by doing

```
df.groupby('Alphabet')['ID'].nunique()
```

and the result is

```
A    1
B    1
C    1
D    1
```

but I want to store Alphabets that does NOT have missing data in them
I want the result to be look like

```
B    1
C    1
```

and from this console result, how would I store "B" and "C" into a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, using `all()`

```
s=df.groupby('Alphabet').apply(lambda x : x.notnull().all()).all(1)

df.groupby('Alphabet').ID.nunique()[s[s].index]
Out[1082]: 
Alphabet
B    1
C    1
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Or

```
df.loc[~df.Alphabet.isin(df.loc[s[s].index,'Alphabet'])].groupby('Alphabet').ID.nunique()
Out[1095]: 
Alphabet
B    1
C    1
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```